# xdg-utils seem to be unavailable on your system

Tags: apt, intellij, xdg

After installing JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA Community edition and going through the customization wizard, hitting the final button labeled "Start Using IntelliJ IDEA" causes a window to pop up saying "Unfortunately, xdg-utils seem to be unavailable on your system".

I followed this Unix StackOverflow question titled "[xdg-open is both installed and not installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101378/xdg-open-is-installed-yet-also-is-not-installed)", leading me to this

```
$ type -a xdg-open
xdg-open is /usr/bin/xdg-open
xdg-open is /bin/xdg-open
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/xdg-open
xdg-utils: /usr/bin/xdg-open
$ dpkg -S /bin/xdg-open
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /bin/xdg-open
```

I get the impression xdg-utils is installed twice but one of them is broken, but normal apt-get stuff like reinstalling doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What is the output of `file /bin/xdg-open`?  I am thinking that one is a symbolic link to the one in `/usr/bin/xdg-open`.

Comment: It says "/bin/xdg-open: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable"

Comment: It looks like the IntelliJ IDEA has an issue detecting if it is installed or not.  http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/community.git;a=commitdiff;h=a2e95cc7dbfc1b704ad6031717d44c3fa26f2258 shows a patch that was done.  I don't have it installed to write up an answer that might be helpful.  If I have time I will try to see if I can duplicate your issue then try to patch it.